# xaf window.close not working. How to close a window?

Tags: c#, winforms, xaf

I tried the following code to close an XAF window.

```
  public static bool CloseViewIfOpen(XafApplication application, string listViewId)
    {
        if (!(application.ShowViewStrategy is WinShowViewStrategyBase strategy)) return false;
        foreach (var win in strategy.Windows.ToArray())
        {
            if (win.View == null) continue;
            if (!win.View.Id.Equals(listViewId)) continue;
            win.Close();
            return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

However the code does not work.
Looking inside the DevExpress.ExpressApp.WinWindow close method, I see that it does nothing and returns false.

[image: Close code]

Is there any other way to close the winwindow in code?

I need to close the XAF window so that I can re-construct it's nested listview collection source.

The user can close the window via the UI.

I am using XAF 21.2.8

The docs are [here](https://docs.devexpress.com/eXpressAppFramework/DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.WinWindow.Close(System.Boolean)?p=net6).

I tried calling win.Dispose but the win.controllers collection remains preventing the dispose.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static bool CloseViewIfOpen(XafApplication application, string listViewId)
    {
        if (!(application.ShowViewStrategy is WinShowViewStrategyBase strategy)) return false;
        foreach (var win in strategy.Windows.ToArray())
        {
            if (win.View == null) continue;
            if (!win.View.Id.Equals(listViewId)) continue;
            win.View.Close();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```